# signed / unsigned ints

Tags: c, int, signed

Let's suppose I have a C script and I declare some unsigned int. Then, I write a while loop which automatically increase the value of these and print them out: no limit until the user stop it from command line. As soon as I reach a very high number (2billions), the computer start counting from -2billions. How can I prevent this? Look, I can easily type, let's say, "99999999999999" without causing any crash: why can't I just do this on my 32bit terminal? I've tried with long long int, signed and unsigned but I still have this problem. Here's a screenshot: http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/6558/schermata20110524a01012.png

Thanks,
J.

Comment: C is _not_ a scripting language.  ;)

Comment: You may be using unsigned storage, but you are printing it as signed. If you are using printf use %u instead of %i or %d.

Answer (score 2):

The computer has no notion of signed/unsigned, it's the matter of interpretation of the values. The same value can be interpreted as -1 or as 65535, depending on how you define your data type. In your case - the loop will never go into the negative numbers, because for that data type - there's no such thing. Instead the positive range will be larger than that of the `signed int`.

As to the screenshot - how are you printing? If you're printing using `%d` for example - it will interpret the values as `signed`. Use `%u` instead to have the program interpret the values as `unsigned`.

Answer (score 2):

How are you printing them out? Are you using `printf("%u", i)`, or `printf("%i", i)`?

`%i` will think the int is signed, even if it isn't. To print an unsigned int, use `%u`.

Comment: `%i` is only correct for `int`, `signed int` and `short`. For `unsigned int`, you should use `%u`, and for `unsigned long long`, `%llu` (But note that some versions of Windows use a non-standard specifier)

Comment: genial - thanks! And how much big an unsigned int can be? I want to store a value which may easily go over 2billions!

Comment: An `unsigned int` can hold values from 0 to `UINT_MAX`. Typically, `UINT_MAX` is 2^32, or 4 billion, but this is platform specific. Likewise, `unsigned long long` has a range of 0-`ULLONG_MAX`. These macros are found in `limits.h`.

Comment: thanks! you guys saved me but... D'oh! Using "unsigned long long int" results in having the program to cause a 3 second latency.

"Measured time: 6 seconds 624 milliseconds"
"Measured time: 9 seconds 297 milliseconds"

Ok anyway, will be improving! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A 32-bit number is limited in range by the fact that it's only got 32-bits. You can't store a 60- 70- etc. bit number in 32 bits.

You can use somthing like `unsigned long long`, which might be 64-bits and thus have a greater range, but it will still have a limit. (2^64, but it's a *very* big number). If you really need "unlimited", look into bigint libraries, such as GMP.

---

**Edit:** as other posters have indicated, be sure you're using the correct conversion specifier in your format string to `printf`:

- `%d`, `%i`: `int`, `signed int`, `short`
- `%u`: `unsigned int`, `unsigned short`
- `%llu`: `unsigned long long`
- `%lld`, `%lli`: `long long`

Note that some versions of Windows have non-standard format specifiers for the `long long` types.

Comment: I've tried to change from int to long long int but the result is the same as posted above in the screenshot :(

Comment: @Joseph: see the posts about which conversion specifier to use with `printf`, that is likely why your attempt with `long long int` failed.

Answer (score 0):

It's partly about how you print the value.

If you say

```
printf("%d\n", your_unsigned_int);
```

then even though the int is unsigned, (assuming you don't have a compiler that warns on such things,) `printf` will treat it as a *signed* int (because that's what `%d` means).

Try `%u` instead of `%d`.

Once you have that fixed, realize that on a 32-bit system, an `int` (signed or not) will typically only be 32 bits in size, and thus will only hold values up to about 4 billion.  If you want values larger than that, you'll need a larger type (like `long long`).  If you do that, you'll need to change your format string to something like `"%ull\n"` (or `"%llu"`?  i forget) as well...or who knows what you'll get.